# Issue hide product single price for variable products on WooCommerce shop and archives pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

Im using this snippet to hide single price if the product is variable. Works fine but not apply on first product variable of loop:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'hide_single_price' );

function hide_single_price() {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
    }
}
```

Any idea why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't immediately see a problem with your current code, what you can try:

- Adjust the priority value
- Echo the text 'debug'. So you can check if that is displayed for the first product.

```php
function hide_single_price() {
    // Get the global product object
    global $product;

    // Is a WC product
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            // Debug purposes, delete afterwards!!
            echo 'DEBUG!';
            
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'hide_single_price', 5 );
```

Comment: Well, your code works, i supuse the trick was "5" priority. Thanks